# Pandas data frame automatically converting into tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datafame df. I want to read columns in dataframe To pass into for loop

```
For i in df.columns:
```

But I’m getting below error.

```
Attribute error: tuple object has no attribute columns.
```

Type of df is pandas dataframe only.

Comment: No it's not possible. Check `print(type(df))` just before `for i in df.columns`

Comment: I have 2 user defined function. 
In 1st function I’m using df_1 =df.copy() after this line I checked type(df) is class ‘pandas.core.frame.Dataframe’.                                             In the next function same df type is tuple.  Not sure why it is changed to tuple

Comment: Please put up some screenshots

Comment: @AnanayMital: Instead screenshots, it should be [mcve] (examples and code) as text.